# Проблема с pthread_cleanup_push()

Tags: c, pthread

Поток main - posix thread. Есть код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void AtExit(void *a) {
    fclose((FILE *)a);
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen(__FILE__, "r");
    pthread_cleanup_push(AtExit, f);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

вот такая ошибки:

```
../src/wdtest.c:14:1: error: expected ‘while’ at end of input
```

и

```
../src/wdtest.c:14:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

С точки зрения моего компилятора (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (без ключа -std, с ключем -pthread (если что))) это ошибка в макросе `pthread_cleanup_push` (поскольку без него все хорошо), однако файл `pthread.h` его ест. Все остальные доступные pthread_* - функции и с ними все хокей. Тех кто считает, что я испортил заголовочный файл прошу НЕ беспокоить. Ответьте те, кто сталкивался. Ubuntu 16.06 x86_64

Comment: А нет ли до того про `EXIT_SUCCESS undeclared`?

Comment: нет без вызова макроса все Ок

Comment: может define какой-нибудь нужен...

Comment: В этом макросе вот такое окончание (проверил не у меня одного):    __pthread_register_cancel (&__cancel_buf);          \
    do {
extern void __pthread_register_cancel (__pthread_unwind_buf_t *__buf)

Comment: Советую скопировать в редактор. Открывающийся цикл do прямо перед объявлением функции??? :(

Comment: с таким без трехголового макромонстра не справится...

Answer (score 4):

Компилятор абсолютно прав, когда выдает Вам ошибку.

Вы неправильно понимаете назначение функции pthread_cleanup_push. Почитайте еще раз внимательно документацию на эту функцию. Например [здесь](http://citforum.ru/programming/unix/threads_2/).

Дело в том, что функция pthread_cleanup_push может быть использована только вместе с функцией pthread_cleanup_pop, причем они должны быть на одном уровне блоков кода. Вот так все работает:

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen(__FILE__, "r");
    pthread_cleanup_push(AtExit, f);
    // some code;
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Дело в том, что макрос pthread_cleanup_push открывает цикл do {, а макрос pthread_cleanup_pop закрывает этот цикл } while (0).

Comment: Вот я дундук...

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE 1

#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void AtExit(int i, void *a) {
    if(!fclose((FILE *)a)) {
        printf("File closed!\n");
    } else {
        printf("File close failure!\n");
    }
}

void AtExit2(int i, void *a) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("/home/vlad/main.c", "r");
    on_exit(AtExit, f);

    if(NULL == f) {
        perror("fopen()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    on_exit(AtExit2, NULL);  
#undef _BSD_SOURCE   

    return 0;
}
```

Для одного потока пойдет